# Python 2.7 Decoding both UTF-8 and unicode-escape in python causes UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, text, unicode, encoding, compiler-errors

I have a tsv file which in some lines a particular column contains mixed formats such as: `Hapoel_Be\u0027er_Sheva_A\u002eF\u002eC\u002e` which should be `Hapoel_Be'er_Sheva_A.F.C.`.

And here is the code I use to read the file and split the columns:

```
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
  for line in f:
      cols = line.decode('utf-8').split('\t')
      text = cols[3].decode('unicode-escape') #Here is the column that has the above mentioned mixed format
```

Error message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0160' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I would like to know how to convert from the first mixed format to the other while reading the file? I'm using python 2.7.

Thank you so much,

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: @FHTMitchell sorry forgot to specify. it's python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the raw bytes into a unicode

```
import ast

raw_bytes = br'Hapoel_Be\u0027er_Sheva_A\u002eF\u002eC\u002e'
print(raw_bytes)  # b'Hapoel_Be\u0027er_Sheva_A\u002eF\u002eC\u002e'

unicode_string = ast.literal_eval('"{}"'.format(raw_bytes.decode('utf8')))
```

output of `unicode_string`:

```
Hapoel_Be'er_Sheva_A.F.C.
```

---

Update - tested in python 2.7 and works a charm

Comment: thank you for the efforts, but it triggers an error I think it's because I'm already decoding the whole line (question is edited accordingly).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `decode('unicode-escape')` to convert those hex sequences to characters.

```
>>> 'Hapoel_Be\\u0027er_Sheva_A\\u002eF\\u002eC\\u002e'.decode('unicode-escape')
u"Hapoel_Be'er_Sheva_A.F.C."
```

Edit: according to your update to the question, you actually have a *combination* of hex sequences and Unicode characters outside of the ASCII range. The error comes from an automatic conversion that Python 2.7 attempts when you try to use `.decode()` on a Unicode string - `decode` only works on byte strings, so it tries to convert from Unicode using the `ASCII` codec. Python 3 won't allow this mistake.

To fix this you need a double conversion, one to convert those non-ASCII characters to hex sequences and another to convert them back. The `'unicode-escape'` codec will double up the backslashes so those must be corrected as well.

```
>>> print u'Hapoel_Be\\u0027er_Sheva_A\\u002eF\\u002eC\\u002e\u0160'.encode('unicode-escape').replace(b'\\\\u', b'\\u').decode('unicode-escape')
Hapoel_Be'er_Sheva_A.F.C.Š
```

Comment: damn that's much better than mine

Comment: @FHTMitchell I always consider any kind of `eval` a last resort. One of the guiding principles of Python was that there should always be one obvious way to do something, but it sure violates that principle a lot.

Comment: @MarkRansom it caused an error. I'll be posting more details and the error message.